# get Service Worker clientId on client

Tags: javascript, service-worker

is there a way to get service worker clientId for specific window on "client side" i.e. when registering service worker? I would like to pass that id from client to serviceWorker when executing a function to then postMessage() in sw back to that client

The only way i found to get clientId is by using onfetch listener in service worker itself, (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/clientId), but since many clients do fetch then the actual clientId doesnt always match the id im trying to get.

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1557